# Assigning data to fields on opening dialog in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've created a dialog box using vuetify and I want it to be prepopulated with data in the v-select but it's blank when I open the dialog modal. I've assigned the `propPackage` to the `selectPackage` which is used in `v-model` in the `v-select`. How should I prepopulate it when I open the dialog?

Dialog

```
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="600px" @click:outside="close">
       <v-select
         :items="['Basic', 'Standard', 'Premium']"
          label="Package*"
          required
          v-model="selectPackage"
          ></v-select>
          <v-btn @click="close"> Close </v-btn>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    dialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    },
    propPackage: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    selectPackage: this.propPackage,
  }),
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.$emit("close");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Parent component

```
<template>
 <v-btn @click="bookDialog('Basic')"></v-btn>
 <form-modal :dialog="openDialog" @close="close" :propPackage="propPackage" />
</template>
<script>
import FormModal from "@/components/FormModal.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    FormModal,
  },
  data: () => ({
    openDialog: false,
    propPackage: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    bookDialog(val) {
      this.propPackage = val;
      this.openDialog = true;
    },
    close() {
      this.openDialog = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70077413-943o6?file=/src/components/FormModal.vue

The main issue is that you're trying to access the prop value directly on your data block:

```js
    data: () => ({
       selectPackage: this.propPackage,
    }),
```

In this case, it would be better to get the prop value by setting up a watcher instead, just like this:

```js
    data: () => ({
      selectPackage: ''
    }),  
    watch: {
      propPackage(val) {
        // Be sure to validate default values
        if(val !== '') {
          this.selectPackage = val
        }
      }
    },
```

This way, you can also validate the prop value if you need to.

I added a few more comments in the codesanbox on things you could improve. Since the **FormModal** component works mainly as a dialog, you can use the **'value'** prop and set up a computed property to be able to close the dialog directly from the child component, this way you avoid emitting a **@close** event to the parent component and the prop mutation warning.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using arrow functions for data section, `this.propPackage` will be undefined since `this` won't refer to vue instance. You can fix that in 2 ways:

1. Change the arrow function to ES6 notation in your dialog component:

   ```
   data() {
      selectPackage: this.propPackage,
   },
   ```
2. Pass the vue instance as a parameter to arrow function and access your prop using that:

   ```
   data: (instance) => ({
      selectPackage: instance.propPackage,
   }),
   ```

Once you populate your `selectPackage` data property the right way, your `v-select` will be populated with the value once you open your dialog.

Comment: the the form dialog is mounted together with the parent component which is why it's not assigned. How would I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: yeah doesn't get assigned due to both dialog and parent component mounting on the dom at the same time

Comment: if I assign the `propPackage: 'Basic'` in data property then it works but it wouldn't work when I do in methods like `bookDialog(val){ this.propPackage=val;  this.openDialog=true`

Comment: If you want more help you can make a reproduction sandbox on https://codesandbox.io/ and I will try to resolve your issue.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-mountain-76qu8?file=/src/components/FormModal.vue  created this codesandbox. says `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "propPackage". Expected String, got Null ` even though I passed 'Basic'